# "at me" vs "at mine"

Tags: grammar, american-english

I'm watching (an American) TV Show where one of the characters says: "[..] treacherous, despicable serpent. Hurling wicked insults at mine every turn".
I instantly noticed how they used an unusual "at mine" instead of "at me". I believe this is the first time I hear someone using that expression, so the question is: is it grammatically correct?

Comment: It sounds like they were speaking in an older version of English.  Like that used in the King James Bible.

Comment: Indeed, that one character was suffering from a schizoaffective disorder and acting as a mass murderer from the 16th century. My apologies for forgetting to mention the details.
So I assume it's an incorrect expression nowadays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not standard grammar; however "at me" is not right either. The right form is "**at my**", where "my" is a modifier of "turn". "At" is not the usual preposition used with "hurl" but the preposition introducing the adverbial of place "at every turn" which takes here a special form: "*at my/her/his/ every turn*". This idiom is not attested in the dictionaries but is found in plenty.

ngrams: [at my every turn](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+my+every+turn&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20my%20every%20turn%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cat%20my%20every%20turn%3B%2Cc0), [at her every turn](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+her+every+turn&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20her%20every%20turn%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cat%20her%20every%20turn%3B%2Cc0), [at his every turn](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+his+every+turn&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20his%20every%20turn%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cat%20his%20every%20turn%3B%2Cc0)

The idiom that explains it and that is found in the dictionaries is "*at every turn*".

> (SOED) **at every turn** at every change of circumstances, at each new stage, continually

A translation of this in Chinese exists and shows that the correct determiner is "my" (found in [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22at+my+every+turn%22&safe=active&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxt8D_89juAhWuA2MBHZepAr4Q_AUICigA&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1)).

[image]

Comment: If you're speaking 16th century English (like the character was apparently trying to do) *at mine every turn* is correct. People used *mine* instead of *my* before words beginning with vowels.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, I thought "at me" was a correct alternative because I thought "every turn" was an independent phrase having a similar meaning to "every time". Please correct me if my interpretation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct but doesn't, usually, mean the same as 'at me'. 'Mine' in this case almost certainly means the speaker's family and other relatives. The term is most familiar from the expression [me and mine](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/me_and_mine) which Lexico defines as:

> My family and relatives.

with examples:

> I consider it a great compliment to me and mine that you would consider our family worthy to be joined.’

and

> Tell your minions to stay away from me and mine

I can't tell from the short context but I expect that the 'Serpent' has been verbally, and possibly physically as well, attacking the speaker's family rather than the speaker personally.